# CSRListForm and PreSaveAction or PreSaveItem

Tags: 2016, client-side-rendering, presaveaction

I've used `PreSaveAction` successfully in the past, but now I'm working with a `CSRListForm` and neither one of these will fire off.  Even if I use just a simple alert message.

I know the `CSRListForm` causes a lot of standard things to not work.  Does it invalidate `PreSaveAction` and `PreSaveItem` as well?

Thanks

Edit:

Sharpoint 2016 On Prem

I'm saving using this method:

```
SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2');
```

The standard Save button has disappeared so I can't use this:

```
$('input[value=Save]').click();
```

My code is based off of this:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSR-code-samples-11-Fully-54ebcaa6

Thank you

Comment: With which version of SharePoint do you want to use CSR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fighting with this for a few days I decided to abandon the CSRListForm method and use the hillbilly.js method specified here:

https://github.com/mrackley/HillbillyTemplate

With this method the following all work:

Standard Save and Cancel; Attach File; PreSaveItem; PreSaveAction

Answer (score 2):

The problem you were having is because you weren't using the standard save button. The standard save button looks kind of like this:

```
<input name="somereallylongname" value="Save"
    onclick="if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;if (SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2')) return false;//etc" 
    id="somereallylongname"
    target="_self" type="button">
```

Notice that the `onclick` event starts with `if(!PreSaveItem()) return false;`, and then it does `if (SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2')) return false;`.  You said you're doing:

```
SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2');
```

to save the form, but that's only a portion of the logic, removing much of the validation. If you had done:

```
if (!PreSaveItem())
    return false;
if (SPClientForms.ClientFormManager.SubmitClientForm('WPQ2'))
    return false;
```

from your own button, validation would have worked the way you expected, including PreSaveItem. All OOB forms in 2016 are CSR forms, and they still work fine with PreSaveItem/PreSaveAction.

Comment: Thanks Joe.  I think I could have gotten this to work but so many other things were affected by using the CSRListForm that I decided not to use it.

Comment: You're welcome. I knew by the time I saw it that you had already moved on to an hillbilly forms, but figured I'd share what I knew.